# Solve two simultaneous equations with three unknowns.

Tags: systems-of-equations

I have 20 iron bars. Some are 3 kg, some are 8 kg and the rest are 14 kg. The total mass of all twenty is 183 kg. Determine the number of each bar.

Let number of 3kg bars = x, 8kg bars = y, 14kg bars = z

So,

$x + y + z = 20\\3x + 8y + 14z = 183$

To solve, "Intelligent trial and error" from here?

Try x=1,x=2,x=3,x=4,x=5 and solve simultaneously for y and z.

Yields x = 5, y = 7, z = 8

i.e. 5x3kg bars, 7x8kg bars, 8x14kg bars

Is it a case of trial and error or is there a "smart solution"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step we can eliminate a variable

- $x + y + z = 20 \iff 3x + 3y + 3z = 60$
- $3x + 8y + 14z = 183$

and subtracting the first one from the other one we obtain

$$5y + 11z = 123$$

which by inspection leads to integer solutions for $z=3$ and $z=8$.

Finally from the first original equation we obtain $(x,y,z)=(5,7,8)$.

Answer (score 2):

Same starting point:
$$\begin{cases}
x+y+z=20\\ 3x+8y+14 z=183
\end{cases} \Longrightarrow \enspace 5y+11z=123
$$
Now, we have the Bézout relation $\;-2\cdot 5+1\cdot 11=1$, which implies
$$-246\cdot5+123\cdot11 =123,$$
whence a solution $y_0=-246,\enspace z_0=123$. Now, it is known that all solutions of the diophantine equation $5y+11z=123$ have the form
$$\begin{cases}
y=y_0+11k,\\
z=z_0-5k.
\end{cases} \quad(k\in\mathbf Z) $$
Furthermore, here we have the constraints
$$\begin{cases}y=-246+11k>0 \\ z=123-5k>0,\end{cases}
\iff \begin{cases}k>22 \\ k<24.\end{cases}$$
Hence there is a single possibility: $\;k=23$, which makes $y=7, z=8$, and consequently $x=5$.